# Rails - Intercept respond_with

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controllers, respond-with

I am using this 3rd party controller:

```
   class LibController

      def update
        # 29 lines of code
        respond_with resource
      end

   end
```

I want to do something other than the `respond_with` at the end. But I don't want to just copy/paste all 29 lines into `MyController.update`. Unfortunately I can't figure out a way to render or redirect anywhere else:

```
   class MyController < LibController

     def update
       super
       redirect_to somewhere_else
     end

   end
```

I get a `DoubleRenderError: Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action`. I assume this is because `respond_with` calls `render` immediately. Is there a way to block/prevent that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing a twice redirection.
Try to remove one redirection on your **update** method.

Check sample code below that shows equivalent response when using **respond_with**.

```
def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])
  flash[:notice] = 'User was successfully created.' if @user.save
  respond_with(@user)
end
```

**Which is exactly the same as:**

```
def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.save
      flash[:notice] = 'User was successfully created.'
      format.html { redirect_to(@user) }
      format.xml { render xml: @user, status: :created, location: @user }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.xml { render xml: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks aldrien. I'm wondering if my only option is to copy/paste the entire method from the 3rd party method, just to replace that last line.

Comment: i think you just need to use the redirection in Controller method, and try to remove the respond_with in "class LibController". Sorry I'm just guessing possible way, since I did not see your full codes. Try to maneuver it, important thing is USE only one redirection.